# Layered Navigation wrong filtering custom attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, layered-navigation

I have added a `couple of custom attributes` to my store. 
The default ones, like category or price is listing and filtering correctly.

By filtering correctly I mean correct displaying all of another filters (along with quantities) and price slider for example.

The problems starts whenever I try to select a custom made attribute. For example "**Płeć**" which is a gender. After selecting, the filters are showing (1) everywhere in products, as well as price slider is stopping to work. What is wrong with filtering ?

Here is my [website](http://mrbobas.pl/ubranka.html) with direct link to one of categories.

Comment: Is there any third party extension for the layered navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen provied page by you, so you are using mageinn

```
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-multiselect-layered-navigation-toolbar-with-price-slider.html
```

module, can you disable that module for some time.**Clear cache, Reindex data, and recheck the same issue.**

Also check `system.log` + `exception.log`.

Any block which is rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` block.

Comment: I have turned off this module, reindexed data and cleared cache. The issue is still occurring.

Comment: Hey, buddy after digging so much on your site i come know that , you are not using pagination of product list folder. It is from magento' s default base folder. So it has collection string which will always lead to print '1'. **AS PER PHP IF COUNT(SOME STRING), IT WILL PRINT 1.** Hope this help you.

Comment: How can I use that knowledge to change the error in displaying ?